# How to use IMPORTHTML for COVID results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is this link: `https://covid19.who.int/table`

[COVID 19 table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU3Fk.png)

It is a table with latest COVID 19 cases.

I tried getting the results in a spreadsheet using a formula

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://covid19.who.int/table","table",1)
```

It gives the error:

> Error Imported content is empty.

How can I make it work? What is wrong?

When I do "inspect" it says `<div role="table" class="sc-pBzUF dgtvEZ"`

Comment: The reason it is not working is because it is not in a table it is technically a div that is formatted like a table. Look for another data set and then right click on the page and "inspect" to see the webpages contents. To see if it is in a table or not.

Comment: @GabrielPierce When I do "inspect" it says <div role="table" class="sc-pBzUF dgtvEZ"

Comment: Yep, its a div pretending to be a table what you would be looking for is something that would say <table> ... </table>

Comment: @GabrielPierce OK. So what do I do? I believe I could use IMPORTXML but I know nothing about it. Can you help/provide a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv",",","en_US")
```